# Is there still a way to send a message with a friend request on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

With the new Facebook layout (timeline, etc.) friend requests are made with one click (the old pop-up box doesn't show up anymore). I tried to send a friend request to someone I hadn't seen in a while with a personal message included but I didn't see an option to do so. Where did the option to send a message with a friend request go? Or is it just gone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook has removed that feature (Sending a message during a friend request). Instead, you can *message* that person just before or after you make the friend request. The Message button is located near the Add Friend button.

[image]

Comment: But that won't help. Because facebook sends all the _messages_ from NOT friends to SPAM

Comment: +1 to [Abhijith's](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/23191) [comment](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22684/is-there-still-a-way-to-send-a-message-with-a-friend-request-on-facebook#comment24337_22709). Notification of messages going to those you are not currently friends with on Facebook, being put it a "different" inbox, is provided near the bottom of the New Message window. However, whether it was once called "SPAM" or not, it is now called "Other" and is found to the right of "Inbox" once the messages tab is open.

Answer (score 1):

I know how to send a message without a message button it is simple - Put this in your URL bar `https://www.facebook.com/messages/[id or name]` and you can send a message right away with friend request send or without.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: It seems to work.

Comment: it is just sending a simple message. It will go to the requests section.. this is not helpful