# Can I send a message to someone who's made a friend request?

Tags: facebook

Someone's made a friend request, but I'm suspicious about the request. The only public detail is her gender, and her name. Googling her name suggests that it's a Nigerian name, so I'm worried it may be a user engaging in a [scam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance-fee_fraud).

I'd like to be able to message her, to ask how she knows me, before accepting the request. The "Respond to Friend Request" only allows "Confirm" and "Delete request", and she doesn't seem to allow messaging from people she doesn't know. Am I missing something, or is it not possible to message someone who has made a friend request, depending on that user's privacy settings?

[Is there still a way to send a message with a friend request on Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22684/is-there-still-a-way-to-send-a-message-with-a-friend-request-on-facebook) looks similar, but it's for the reverse: a requester sending a message, not a requestee sending a message. I can see the logic for not allowing the former, as it could be abused as a way of spamming, but I can't see the logic for not allowing the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, even if you have received a friend request from her, you may not be able to Send her a message depending on her privacy settings.

What you can do here is accept her friend request; then place her under the list called, "Restricted" and then send her a message. Later you can remove her from your friend list.

Or, if you are sure that you do not know her (or anybody with that Nigerian Name); you can cancel her friend request.